# comparing date from db on laravel use sql

Tags: php, sql, laravel, date, comparison

im trying to compare date from db on laravel but the comparison is failed probably wrong way to compare

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$dateUp= Jadwal::where('pembibitan', ">" ,strtotime($today))->get();;
$date= Jadwal::where('pembibitan', '<' ,strtotime($today))->get();;
    
    return view('dashboard',['date'=>$date ,'dateUp'=>$dateUp, 'today'=>$today]);
```

the output end up with foreach display all data that exist on db

Comment: pembibitan format in db

Comment: SQL? I see no SQL here.

Comment: date type for pembiibitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `whereDate` since you have date column in database

```
$dateUp= Jadwal::whereDate('pembibitan', ">" ,$today)->get();
```

As per official documention

> The whereDate method may be used to compare a column's value against a
> date